# Is it possible to write a launcher widget or live wallpaper for Android in Monogame?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, monogame

Is it possible to write a launcher widget or live wallpaper for Android in Monogame?

So far the only example I can find of a widget with Monodroid at all is a wiktionary word-of-the-day widget which has absolutely no supporting documentation or explanation of what it's doing, no examples of live wallpapers at all, and nothing at all on MonoGame doing anything outside of full-screen apps.

So I'm expecting the only answer will be a resounding "no" or at best "it's possible but NFI how"... but it's worth a shot.